# Mercurial Nested Repo Issue

Tags: mercurial, repository, nested

I have accidentally created a repo in a sub directory of another repo

Since doing this the sub repo now contains a number of commits

I realised my mistake when I attempted an hg st on the original (parent?) repo and it complained of a file being inside a nested repo

What I would like to do is somehow move the sub repo history up into the parent then just delete the sub repo so I have just one repo

The dir structure is like this:

my original repo:

```
core/
```

my directories containing src code i'm trying to version control:

```
core/src/
core/test/
```

my accidental repo is in:

```
core/src/
```

e.g. its this one I want to push?/merge? up a level into the `core/` repo, then just kill the `core/src/` repo (by deleting the .hg dir)

I have read a few stack overflow discussions on this but they seem to be trying to solve more complicated sub repo scenarios. I'm hoping a straightforward (dare i say it simple) solution may exist?

I have not had much luck with the HG wiki on this either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Preserving history

Depending on the version you're using, you can use the [Transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) or [Graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft) extension to achieve your goal.

I've never done that and don't have time to test it before hand, but something like the following steps should work :

1. Move your actual `core/src/` dir somewhere else, for example `~/temp.subrepo/`
2. Remove the subrepo from the `.hgsub` file
3. Use the [Convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) to rename the files in the subrepo (see below for a quick example)
4. Transplant the changes : hg transplant -s ~/temp.subrepo.converted/ 0:tip

To convert the subrepo, you can use something like this :

```
$ echo include . > /tmp/myfilemap
$ echo rename . src/ >> /tmp/myfilemap
$ hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap ~/temp.subrepo/ ~/temp.subrepo.converted/
```

Like I said, I'm not sure this will work out of the box, but it's at least a lead. If you have any problem, don't hesitate to ask.

#### History doesn't matter

Or maybe the simplest solution is just to remove the `.hg` directory in the subrepo, remove any mention of the subrepo in the `.hgsub` file of the main repo, and just add and commit the files :

```
hg add core/src
hg commit
```

You will lose all the history of the subrepo, but at least the solution is really simple.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe i will just forgo the history in this instance for an easy life. I do find DVCS complex, I'm hoping at some point it will 'click' as they say - thanks for the pointers...